# Setup complex line integral $\int_{\gamma}x^2+y^2 dz$, where $\gamma$ is the line segment from $i+2$ to $-i-1$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-integration, line-integrals

Question 1. Is this correct? I have to evaluate

> $\int_{\gamma}x^2+y^2 dz$, where $\gamma$ is the line segment from $i+2$ to $-i-1$

Step 1: Equation of line passing through $(2,1)$ and $(-1,-1) $is $y=\frac{2x-1}{3}$. Then, the line segment in the direction from $-i-1$ to $i+2$  is $\psi(t)=[t,\frac{2t-1}{3}]$, $\psi:[-1,2] \to \mathbb R^2$ (or $\mathbb C$).

Step 2: Thus, to have $\psi = -\gamma$, where the negative indicates opposite direction s.t. $\gamma$ is the line segment in the direction from $i+2$ to $-i-1$, we do $\gamma(a+b-t)=:-\gamma(t)=\psi(t)$, where $a=-1,b=2$.

Step 3 Solving for $\gamma(t)$, we get $\psi(a+b-t)=\gamma(t)$. Hence, $\gamma(t)=[1-t,\frac{2(1-t)-1}{3}]$, $\gamma:[-1,2] \to \mathbb R^2$ (or $\mathbb C$).

Step 4: Therefore, $\int_{\gamma}x^2+y^2 dz$

$$= \int_{-1}^2 ((1-t)^2+(\frac{2(1-t)-1}{3})^2) [(-1)+i(-\frac23)]dt$$

$$ = \int_{-1}^2 ((1-t)^2+(\frac{2(1-t)-1}{3})^2) [(-1)]dt$$

$$+i \int_{-1}^2 ((1-t)^2+(\frac{2(1-t)-1}{3})^2) [(-\frac23)]dt$$

$$=...\text{(easy to check wolfram. see below)}$$

$$= -4+i(\frac{-8}{3})$$

Wolfram: [real part](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E2%20%28%281-t%29%5E2%2B%28%5Cfrac%7B2%281-t%29-1%7D%7B3%7D%29%5E2%29%20%5B%28-1%29%5Ddt). [imaginary part](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E2%20%28%281-t%29%5E2%2B%28%5Cfrac%7B2%281-t%29-1%7D%7B3%7D%29%5E2%29%20%5B%28-%5Cfrac23%29%5Ddt).

---

Question 2. Btw $x^2+y^2 = |z|^2$ right?

Comment: did you get the line by using $(2,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$? Also, you're "btw" is correct. To see this let $z=x+iy$ then $\vert z \vert^2 = z \overline{z}=(x+iy)(x-iy)=x^2+y^2.$ I am unsure however on how you got $[-2,1]$ and not $[-1,2]$. Maybe I am not seeing something.

Comment: @HossienSahebjame oh yeah what a weird mix up. edited. thanks